# PowerShell Error Creating XLSX

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

Okay, I have 6 CSVs each containing one column.  For this example, the data from the first CSV is used to create the initial document, and each after that is attempting to save to the document.

```
#ID

  $csvFile = "$path\ID.csv"
  $fpath = $Filename 
$processes = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false 
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.add() 
$excel.cells.item(1,1) = "ID" 
$i = 2 
foreach($process in $processes) 
{ 
 $excel.cells.item($i,1) = $process.ID 
 $i++ 
} #end foreach process 
$workbook.saveas($fpath) 
$Excel.Quit() 
Remove-Variable -Name excel 
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 

#SRP

  $csvFile = "$path\SRP.csv" 

$processes = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false 
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.add() 
$excel.cells.item(1,2) = "SRP" 
$i = 2 
foreach($process in $processes) 
{ 
 $excel.cells.item($i,2) = $process.SRP 
 $i++ 
} #end foreach process 
$workbook.save($fpath) 
$Excel.Quit() 
Remove-Variable -Name excel 
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

When I get down to the save line on the second one (`#SRP` section) I get the following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Save" and the argument count: "1".
At D:\UserAdminScripts\0_Powershell_Test_Scripts\Scripts_For_Lisa\NED Stuff\NED_Reports.ps1:130 char:15
+ $workbook.save <<<< ($fpath) 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

If I let the script run after the error, I get the same result for each column.

I'm aware this script isn't clean, because I don't need to close and reopen Excel for each run, but I butchered this script from http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/09/copy-csv-columns-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-by-using-powershell.aspx.  The `saveas` works correctly in the first attempt, it's just the `save` causing an error.

I find when I break the script, I get a pop-up to confirm whether or not I want to make changes to Book2.xlsx.  I tell it yes and I check and Book2 has the 2nd column filled out with the data I wanted as the second column on my original sheet.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would taking out the `$workbook.saveas($fpath)` 
`$Excel.Quit() `
`Remove-Variable -Name excel` 
`[gc]::collect()` 
`[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()` completely until I've tried to add all 6 columns, and not doing any of that until the very end be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I answered my own question, due to ConanW's inspiration to actually, you know, think critically.  The answer to my issue is as follows:

```
#ID

  $csvFile = "$path\ID.csv"
  $fpath = $Filename 
$processes = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false 
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.add() 
$excel.cells.item(1,1) = "ID" 
$i = 2 
foreach($process in $processes) 
{ 
 $excel.cells.item($i,1) = $process.ID 
 $i++ 
} #end foreach process 


#SRP

  $csvFile = "$path\SRP.csv" 

$processes = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile 
$excel.cells.item(1,2) = "SRP" 
$i = 2 
foreach($process in $processes) 
{ 
 $excel.cells.item($i,2) = $process.SRP 
 $i++ 
} #end foreach process 
$workbook.saveas($fpath) 
$Excel.Quit() 
Remove-Variable -Name excel 
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `$Workbook` object with `Get-Member`:

```
Save                             Method                void Save ()
```

The Save() method doesn't accept any arguments and it's failing to work out what to do with that method and your file name argument.

You Quit the Excel app in the #ID section (thus closing the file) so you need to reopen the file before accessing the workbook and trying to write to it.

Comment: P.S. I've spent some time messing about with Office COM objects and have found them unwieldy and complex. I have recently found an excellent PowerShell Module that provides much faster Excel functions and is much simpler to use. Try it out, it may be suitable for your needs. It doesn't even need Excel installed. Look at this page on GitHub (thanks to the author dfinke): [https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: I don't know if you saw my comment on my question.  Is that what you mean?  And I bet I don't need to keep calling this:  `$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false 
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.add()` right?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Yes, if you don't close it, you won't have to reopen it :) Seriously though, check out that module.

Comment: I'd love to but I can't install any other tools.  I get PS v2 and Quest and that's it.

Comment: You should also check that your excel process has gone when you try and `.Quit()` it. I've had problems with it never dying and ending up with tens of excel processes running, especially when often opening a new one.